# How do I turn line break in .docx into line breaks in HTML using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am reading .docx files using `zip_read()`, I realize that in .docx, a page break has the coded of `<w:br w:type="page"></w:br>`. I want to turn it into `<br style="page-break-before: always">` so I can output it into HTML. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: how about `str_replace` ?

Comment: seems not working

Comment: we can't guess at your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an XML file format, so you can read it with DOM:

```
$xml = <<< WORD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:br w:type="page"></w:br>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
WORD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('w', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml');

// find all the page breaks
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//w:br[@w:type="page"]') as $page_break) {
    // create an html break element with some style attribute
    $html_break = $dom->createElement('br');
    $html_break->setAttribute('style', 'page-break-before: always');
    // replace the page break with the html break in the document
    $page_break->parentNode->replaceChild($html_break, $page_break);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

This will convert the word page breaks to html page breaks as requested:

```
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"><w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <br style="page-break-before: always">
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Not that it would make much sense given that the remainder of the word xml is still as it was. But that's how you'd deal with it using an XML parser.

Make sure to check out https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord as well